# GridFS with Laravel doesn't work

Tags: mongodb, laravel-5, gridfs

I'm using multiple db connections and the main is mysql, so I'm trying to get GridFS like this:

```
$grid = DB::connection('mongo')->getMongoDB()->getGridFS();
```

But it's throwing "Call to undefined method MongoDB\Database::getGridFS()".

I've checked phpinfo and pecl drivers mongo and mongodb are up to date. mongodb/mongodb is also 1.0.2 which is up-to-date.

Some thoughts maybe?

Comment: What Mongo driver are you using? `getGridFS()` is a method provided by the now deprecated `mongo` driver, while you might have the `mongodb` driver in use.

Comment: Hi, @code-kobold! I do think that I'm using mongoldb driver, should I use old one? If it is deprecated there should be a substitute for that or more convenient method right?

Comment: Unfortunately, the low-level `mongodb` driver does not provide such an API; this [library](https://packagist.org/packages/mongodb/mongodb) might help you.

Comment: @code-kobold But I'm using it. As dependency to [jenssegers/laravel-mongodb](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb) Seems that they working to have GridFS support in 1.1, but stable release and even last master branch code doesn't have getGridFS in Database class.

Answer (score 0):

In new versions you can use `Bucket` class for upload and download documents to mongodb grid on mongo-php-library 2.2 driver. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41489037/using-gridfs-under-laravel-5-3-with-mongo-php-library-2-2-driver/42600435#42600435).