# Using Gridfs under Laravel 5.3 with mongo-php-library 2.2 driver

Tags: php, laravel-5, gridfs

We use PHP7, latest MongoDB PECL package (1.2.2) - Laravel 5.3 - jenssegers/laravel-mongodb 3.1

I want to use GridFS. It's normally available into the MongoDB PECL package but there are no documentation nor working code example.

Comment: Where you able to apply gridFS with laravel-mongodb? if so, can you provide a snippet code as an answer. That would be very useful

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution ? i need to store a file in a specific mongodb document but gridfs doc is not really good

Comment: I made it work finally. The documentation in 2017 had room to improvement. I do not remember how I did and I don't have access anymore to this repo... You can try https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb/issues/826#issuecomment-290362789

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Bucket` class for upload and download documents to mongodb grid on mongo-php-library 2.2 driver.

```
//upload file
$bucket = \DB::connection('mongodb')->getMongoDB()->selectGridFSBucket();
$resource = fopen($file_path, "a+");
$file_id = $bucket->uploadFromStream($file_path, $resource);

//download file
$bucket = \DB::connection('mongodb')->getMongoDB()->selectGridFSBucket();
$file_metadata = $bucket->findOne(["_id" => $file_id]);
$path = $file_metadata->filename;

if(!file_exists($path)) {
    $downloadStream = $bucket->openDownloadStream($file_id);
    $stream = stream_get_contents($downloadStream, -1);
    $ifp = fopen($path, "a+");
    fwrite($ifp, $stream);
    fclose($ifp);
}
```

Comment: Note that $file_id variable is an ObjectId, if you have an string value, you need to convert to ObjectId: $file_id = new \MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID($str_file_id);

Answer (score 0):

You can go through this [link](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb/issues/231). This shows how you can use gridFS with Laravel-mongodb and also you might need to update your mongo db drivers for this.

Another [link](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb/issues/838) for your reference.

Though there is not a sample code provided there, but it would help you if you have worked over Mongo with Laravel.

Hope it would help you

Comment: I found also those links... but without code examples and documentation, it's far from trivial